# Is Java free to use/ deploy and build large web applications?

Tags: language-agnostic

Simple question, I want to know is Java free (especially for web development). Later on if I've build a large website, will the servers, databases cost me much like in .net for example?

Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Java is free. Check licences of frameworks you're using, but you shouldn't worry about that since most of them are free.

Servers (physical) will, of course, cost you.

There are free application servers like Glassfish and JBoss.

There are free databases like mySQL and PostgreSQL.

So, you can get away with everything being free except hardware and, possibly, hosting of your web app.

Comment: If I will choose managed VPS, will that cost much comparing to windows and linux? By the way I would like to search about java hosting and have a look what should I write? java hosting? jsp?

Comment: @user509953: there is no single answer to your first question. Look around, see some offers, see how much they cost and what you get for your money. Also, stuff like can be geographically dependent. If you're going to ask around, to be sure you won't have any problems, ask for Java hosting on a Java EE 6 compliant application server. Or at least a servlet container like Tomcat. Both can handle jsp.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no - depending on how big your site gets, you may be required to invest more money into better servers/databases.

It's not really something that can just be answered, without looking into the future.

Answer (score 0):

## Update, as of 2021

Be sure to read the document prepared by pillars of the Java community, [*Java is Still Free*](https://medium.com/@javachampions/java-is-still-free-2-0-0-6b9aa8d6d244). This document provides a short overview as well as a longer section with all the gory details.

Understand that Java is a set of specifications, not a product.

- [Java Language and Virtual Machine Specifications](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/)
- [JEPs](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/0) and [JSRs](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/overview)

Many vendors provide binaries or installers for an implementation of Java. Nowadays, all of those implementations are based largely or entirely on the [*OpenJDK*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenJDK) project. Participants including Oracle, IBM, SAP, Apple, Azul Systems, and more have banded together to pool their best technologies for implementing Java as open-source free-of-cost.

The OpenJDK project provides only source-code. Various vendors build that source code to provide binaries or installers for you and me to conveniently put Java on our computers. Some of their distributions of Java are available free-of-cost, and some are commercial with paid support. Some are general-purpose [JVMs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine), and some are special-purpose. Some are a basic [JDK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Development_Kit) and some have bundled extras.

Here is a diagram I made to help you in choosing a vendor for a Java implementation.

[image: Flowchart guiding you in choosing a vendor for a Java 11 implementation]

And some considerations to think about when choosing a vendor.

[image: Motivations in choosing a vendor for Java]